# Decrease minimum depth of a RGBD camera

Tags: cameras, kinect

I have a Kinect camera which has a minimum depth of 0.5m and I'm trying to find a way to decrease it to around 0.2m for near-depth detection. Does anyone know how this can be done? Can a macro lens be added to the IR camera to decrease the minimum depth? Would I then need to calibrate the extrinsics?

Comment: I can somehow be done, but you will spent so much time and money that it will be easier to buy a camera with a shorter minimal distance.

Comment: @FooBar Oh. Which part of the 'hack' is the difficult part?

Comment: Everything. Finding lenses, fixing lenses, redoing intrinsic calibration for projector and camera. Maybe also somehow lowering the exposure for the IR-camera. Depending on the pattern, the projected dots could be to close to be reliable separated....   So just invest 100$ and get a new camera.

Comment: @FooBar Agree. You can do it but will experience all sort of problems.